# Erron::EACCESS error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, windows-vista

I am using windows vista OS, and when I tried to execute a method in the controller, I get this error

> Errno::EACCES in Data
>   phoneController#phone_selection 
>   Permission denied -
>   C:/multi/PHONE/rails/logprints/Andrew

I believe this is just a permission error (isn"t it?) but when I change the permission folder for windows vista, still does not remove the error. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, Errno::EACCESS is usually a permissions error.  What is your phone_selection action trying to do?  It is possible the code is trying to write to different folder than the one you changed the permissions for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the permissions on other folders such as log files and
Temporary correct?